# Building a minimal Linux for Raspberry Pi

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi

Now I got my Raspberry Pi. I am an experienced application software developer, but I've never done hardware stuff or low-level programming before. I want to build a minimal Linux, including drivers for all hardware on my Pi. For learning purpose, I don't want to install any pre-built Linux distribution on my Pi. Where should I start?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also check out Buildroot, http://buildroot.org. We have a default configuration for the Rasberry-Pi, and several contributors are working on the support for this platform.

Answer (score 4):

Start with [openembedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page). There are several links already dedicated to raspberry pi, such as:

- http://www.pimpmypi.com/blog/blogPost.php?blogPostID=7
- http://blogs.distant-earth.com/wp/?p=377
- http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/LayerIndex