# building cross-compiler with --- GTK+ & X11 libraries

Tags: linux, x11, cross-compiling

I have made my cross compiler using `crosstool-ng` :--
http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/

Now i have to cross compile wxGTK using this cross compiler.
wxGTK requires `GTK+ & X11` libraries to build. But my cross-compiler is
not build for the support of the same.

1> X11 library packages required are :----

```
 wx2.8-headers  
 libwxgtk2.8-0  
libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

2> X11 client requires following Package  :---

```
libx11-dev
```

Please suggest to configure crosstool-ng for GTK+ & X11 support in
cross-compiler, this command is correct or not :-----

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/cross  --with-x11 --with-libx11-dev
--with-wx2.8-headers --with-libwxgtk2.8-0 --with-libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

Regards,

//Allan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a solution such as Openembedded to build all the software you need? Compiling X, GTK and WX by hand is not trivial and time consuming

As I suggested [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598457/building-a-minimal-linux-for-raspberry-pi), I'd rather use Openembedded