# How to link busybox install with the kernel

Tags: embedded-linux

I have build the kernel and the busybox. Now, I want to link the kernel with the busybox image. How can I do it? Basically, I want to create an initrd image that has my kernel linked with busybox. I could see my busy_box output is in _install/. Inside _install there are plenty of binaries like ls,cat,etc (rfs). Now, I want to link this rootfile system created from busybox with the kernel. So that the image is initrd. What changes I need to do in kernel to point that newly build busybox rootfile system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a minimal Linux for Raspberry Pi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598457/building-a-minimal-linux-for-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 0):

@Shreyas, easiest way to link and test rfs is by making rfs to be shared over the network i.e. as network filesystem NFS. Need to configure and install packages for NFS to work on your host/development system. Please google for NFS configuration. While passing the boot arguments to kernel, need to pass the absolute path where your root filesystem. For ex: **root=/dev/nfs nfsroot="ip_addr of host system":"absolute path to the root filesystem" rw**