# How do I make a linux image which is of my current system?

Tags: linux, distro

I want a really minimalistic version of linux to run on my raspberry pi. I need nothing on it apart form the tools to make it work. I can then install the things I need such as python, nano, ssh etc.

Is there a version of linux like that? I was thinking ubuntu snappy but wasn't too sure.

Secondly. If i got it configured exactly how I wanted on my system, is it possible to convert it make to a .img file so that I could flash it onto an SD card to use exactly the same settings on 3/4 of my raspberry Pi s?

Thanks

Comment: This question doesn't belong on this site. You should post it on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DanCundy Although I mentioned a raspberry pi, that was just the specific situation I would apply it to. Anybody could do exactly the same thing with any device that booted Linux.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Try the one above or  http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DanCundy Ok, I tried the raspberry pi one.

Comment: I personally have used Raspbian in a previous pi build.

Comment: @DanCundy I'm using that at the moment but I want a linux version that doesn't have stuff I don't need. I want it to literally be enough for me to type the I install all software so I know exactly what is on there. I was thinking of writing my own disto but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Related : [Building a minimal Linux for Raspberry Pi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598457/building-a-minimal-linux-for-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 1):

If can try to debootstrap from Debian/ubuntu. this is the minimal set of packages you might have without too much hack.

If I remember correctly, it installs only 42 packages and you might expand this system with apt.

You can create a simple chroot to try  using something like:

```
$ mkdir jessie-chroot
$ debootstrap jessie ./jessie-chroot http://ftp.debian.org/debian
```

For more information, you can see:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/debootstrap-minimal-debian-ubuntu-installation/